# Loop result is different when adding debug output (Heisenbug?)

Tags: c++

I have a loop that behaves differently if I add debug output in the loop. I wonder if this is a compiler bug, or if I by mistake rely on some undefined `C++` behavior.

The loop reads integers from a `uint64_t` array, stores them in a temp array, and sum the entries. I expect the sum to be larger than 60 because of the data I have.

If it is smaller than 60 (a surprise), I re-try the same loop, this time adding debug output. I would expect the same smaller-than-60 result, but now I get larger than 60.

```
uint64_t test[8];
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    test[i] = overflow[index + i];
}
int temp[64];
int count2 = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
    int cj = (int) ((test[j / 8] >> (8 * j)) & 0xff);
    count2 += cj;
    temp[j] = cj;
}
if (count2 < 60) {
    int count3 = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
        int cj = (int) ((test[j / 8] >> (8 * j)) & 0xff);
        temp[j] = cj;
        ::std::cout << " foo\n";
        count3 += cj;
    }
    ::std::cout << "count2 " << count2 << " count3 " << count3 << "\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
foo
...
foo
count2 6 count3 62
```

The direction of the loop is irrelevant (same result if the loop goes from 0 to 63). There is only one thread. If I comment the cout in the second loop, I get e.g. **"count2 4 count3 4"** (some the original, unexpected case). As soon as I do any kind of cout (even "foo") in the loop, I get count2 != count3 again. I tried to make the first loop more complex (unnecessarily multiply cj by 100), but the same result.

Compiler options in the Makefile:

```
OPT = -O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native
CXXFLAGS += -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -std=c++11 $(OPT)
LDFLAGS = -Wall
```

The same result with LLVM and g++.

The problem goes away with `"-O2"` (g++, didn't try LLVM).

Comment: Can you please [edit] a [mcve] into the question? What's `index`? What's `count3`? Are you perhaps (somewhat ironically) running out of bounds of the buffer pointed to by `overflow`?

Comment: Sure I understand the desire to have a minimal test case... I might be possible, but would be quite a lot of work. But sorry for the bugs in the code, `count3` is a new integer... fixed it. Would it matter if it's out of bounds?

Comment: It can't be that much work. Show how you allocate `overflow`, and what `index` is. You don't have to show code which computes it using complex business logic in your real case. Just show the *results* of that business logic here. (E.g. `int index = 57; // computed by business logic in my real code`). And if that no longer reproduces the issue, you'll have a hint that the problem is in the omitted parts, not in the code in the question.

Comment: And of course it would matter if you run out of bounds. Accessing memory you don't own (such as out of the bounds of a dynamically allocated array) is Undefined Behaviour (i.e. a bug) and anything can happen.

Comment: `(overflow[index + j / 8] >> (8 * j))` is undefined when `j` is >= 8.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ah, looks like that's the problem! (I'm used to Java where this is well defined... Missed that case.)

Comment: @molbdnilo You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: Yes, the the problem was `>>` by some value larger than 63. Thanks a lot!

Comment: While you are at it, you are on a MAC - so use clang and use its static code analyzer. It just might show you what you miss. https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/

Comment: @BitTickler good point! I don't do much C / C++, so didn't try that yet. But will try it once I use C / C++ more often.

Comment: Are you using the `temp` array for further processing? If you only need the sum, there are other [tricks](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MYVjhXIB8UDyh9G1) you can experiment.

Comment: @Bob__ I found the problem, it was the shift

Comment: @molbdnilo could you write it as an answer (shift by x undefined if x >= 64), I will then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ (and C), shifting a k-bit integer in any direction by more than k-1 bits is undefined.

Thus, `(overflow[index + j / 8] >> (8 * j))` is undefined when `j >= 8`, and this can (apparently) cause very different behaviours in your two loops.

I think this should produce the expected result:

```
int temp[64] = {0};
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    int cj = (int) ((test[j / 8] >> (8 * j)) & 0xff);
    count2 += cj;
    temp[j] = cj;
}
```